# In align environment, put both an equation number on the left and a tag on the right?

Tags: equations, align, amsmath

I am writing a report and I would like an equation number on the right hand side, but to label the equation with a word that would appear on the left hand side. However, when I do this using \tag{} in the align environment, it just replaces the equation number with tag. People have suggested using \leqno and this does put the tag on the left (as I want), but now it gets rid of the equation number and only shows the tag. Is there a way to have both?

This is some model code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[leqno]{amsmath}
\newcommand{\leqnomode}{\tagsleft@true}

\begin{document}

\begin{align} \leqnomode
    n(r, t) = \int x dx \tag{Density}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you employ an `flalign` environment, along the following lines.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}   % for 'flalign' environment
\usepackage{showframe} % optional: draw frame lines around text block

\begin{document}

\begin{flalign} 
\text{Density} && n(r,t) &= \int x\,dx &&
\end{flalign}

\end{document}
```

With this solution, the equation (here: `n(r,t) = \int x\,dx`) is centered between the word "Density" on the far left and the equation number on the far right. If, alternatively, you want the equation to be centered horizontally on the entire line, irrespective of the length of the string that's printed on the far left, just change `\text{Density}` to `\rlap{Density}`.